# Geoserver security and application security separation

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, openlayers, security

I am using geoserver that publises WMS, WFS services to clients. I am using geoserver services in an OpenLayers application. My application will requiere username and password authentication.

1 - For example I have a polyline data published WMS. If a user is working on Arizona, she/he can see only Arizona polylines. Can I configure this on geoserver. Or should I do on application?

2- Geoserver admin panel is including Users/Groups/Roles menu. Should I use this users and roles in OpenLayers applicaiton?

How can I specify the security way?

Comment: The geofence project may help. I'd start with reviewing the talk that Mauro did on it at FOSS4G - http://vimeo.com/106221740

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to implement a Proxy like [this](https://github.com/geosolutions-it/http-proxy) that could verify a users credentials as logged in using session variables and only allow them to access resources they are entitled to, ie: check the url for the layers that are being called and deny access if user is not authorized to view them.

In terms of what data they may see, if it is a subset of a larger data set, this is a little more complicated but I see two approaches ..

1. Use [Parameterized SQL Views](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) to control what data the user would see. You could use the Proxy to change the url before it is passed to Geoserver with the parameters specific to that user. You could also send the parameters back to Openlayers via an Ajax Call after the user is authenticated and supply the parameters as part of the WMS getMAP call in OpenLayers. The actual data displayed could be handled by [Variable substitution in SLD](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/substitution.html#variable-substitution-in-sld) to filter data displayed or by using [External Styles](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.5.x/en/user/styling/sld-working.html) in your WMS getMap calls to change the SLD a user uses to display a given layer.
2. Use an Ajax Call after User Authentication to specify [Map Extents](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/restricted-extent.html) to only allow the user to mover around a specified area. You could also use layerVisibility() to restrict what data could be displayed as well.

Comment: This can be easily done with geofence.http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/community/geofence/index.html.